# Create a custom UIButton with text and icon

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I would like to create a custom `UIButton` looking like this:

[image]

The idea is simple, I want the `titleLabel` to start 24px from the leading, and stop 12px or more to the icon image (which is the square view at the right of the button). It can contain up to 2 lines.

The thing is that I have no idea where I should put this code in a class inheriting from `UIButton`.

What should go into `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`?

Also, should I use the `titleLabel` and `titleEdgeInsets` `UIButton` properties and the `imageView`/`imageEdgeInsets` as well, or instead use custom properties for this?

Comment: Do you need this to be a button? Should the whole thing respond to a tap, or just the (I'm assuming) check-box? Will the text be dynamic? Max of 2 lines, or maybe more? Is this for a multiple-choice kind of thing, where it may be better to use a table view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want these buttons to work, be tapped, and react somehow?
These buttons are custom buttons, and you may a create a `Cocoa Touch Class` file for them; name it and let it inherit from and be a subclass of `UIButton`.

Then connect that file to your buttons in the storyboard.
But first, you need to set/attach the newly created file to your buttons. Click on the button, In the identity inspector of your storyboard, with your button selected go to the `Class` field and type the name of your new file and don't forget to tap 'return' to save your changes.

Now, your buttons are attached to that custom UIButton class.
From now, you can attach all your icon images and many more as outlets to your custom UIButton Class you just created.

Most importantly, now these buttons can be used **on their own**; they can be outlets or trigger action methods. And to make it look just as you except, you just have to initialize your buttons, i.e. provide an icon image, text, etc.

Is what I wrote clear?
If not, I am glad to help you.